# CRM 2011 Show/Hide Ribbon Group

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am running across conflicting information about hiding / showing a group of buttons on the ribbon. My custom buttons are in specific groups and rather than target each button I thought it would be better to just show / hide the group as they will all either show or not.

In summary I have found obtuse references with no clear cut procedure for targeting a group....but I have come across circumstantial blogs that indicate it may be possible.

On the other hand I KNOW that if I target each button and hide them all the group will go away.

So which is it? If I can hide a group of buttons on the ribbon then so clear instruction / article etc. would be very much appreciated.

TIA
JB

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide the whole group. Just use the hidecustomaction as you would to hide a single button. This is done in the customizations.xml and under the ribbonDiff element.

Here I have hidden the Data group on incident.

```
<CustomActions>
   <HideCustomAction Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.MainTab.ExportData" HideActionId="crmn.HomepageGrid.incident.MainTab.ExportData.HideAction" />
</CustomActions>
```

Comment: Yes but can I dynamically add / remove it...I didn't think so.